# Getting "Authentication required" error when attempting to use systemService with Sitecore GraphQL

Tags: graphql

I'm trying to use the example `/sitecore/api/graph/items/master` endpoint for Sitecore GraphQL, which uses the `systemService` security configuration. However when I visit `/sitecore/api/graph/items/master/ui`, I get an *Authentication required* error. I am logged into Sitecore and can access the Launchpad and Content Editor. How can I use this GraphQL example and `systemService`?

Answer (score 3):

When using Sitecore Identity Service for login (default on Sitecore 9.1+), you must configure additional URLs for which Sitecore will apply authentication cookies. For this example, a configuration patch on your CM such as the following would accomplish this:

```xml
<configuration>
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <owin.cookieAuthentication.validateIdentity>
        <processor type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Pipelines.CookieAuthentication.ValidateIdentity.ValidateSiteNeutralPaths, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
          <siteNeutralPaths hint="list">
             <path hint="graphql">/sitecore/api/graph/items/</path>
          </siteNeutralPaths>
        </processor>
      </owin.cookieAuthentication.validateIdentity>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Additionally, if using Headless Services 18.0+, the new GraphQL Playground IDE used for the GraphQL UI will not pass cookies by default. In the Settings (accessible via the gear icon the upper right corner), change `request.credentials` to `same-origin` and click *Save Settings*.

[image: Settings with request.credentials]